# What does feel rewarded mean?

Tags: adjectives

What does the term '*feel rewarded*' mean?

> He felt rewarded when his daughter told him she was happy.

Does it mean to be '*proud*'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **reward** someone for something is to give them something good (praise, prize money, acknowledgement and thanks, a token gift, whatever) for their deed.  A reward is any kind of appropriate recognition for deeds.

**reward** is a transitive verb. The past participle of transitive verbs can be used in passive constructions.

> He was **rewarded** by the town with a plaque for his efforts in support
>   of the library.

The past participle of transitive verbs can also be used as an adjective expressing a state; here the state is  "having been rewarded"; and thus the past participle can be used as a predicate adjective or subject complement:

> He felt rewarded.

He felt himself *to have been rewarded*.  He feels as if he has received some kind of recognition for his deeds as a father when his daughter tells him that she is happy.

His reward is his daughter's happiness.   You could say that he felt some pride in his daughter's sense of wellbeing, since he feels that it is the result, at least in part, of the paternal care he has shown her.